# How do I split tab in C#?

Tags: c#, split

[image]

```
string line = "aaa     bbb      ccc      dd! d!";
string[] lineArray = line.Split(new char[] { '\t' });

Console.WriteLine($"{lineArray[0]}");
```

I don't know why it never works.

Comment: _never works_ is not a description of the problem that you are experiencing. Please explain what is not working.

Comment: *I don't know why it never works* ... because four spaces are not a tabulator ?

Comment: Your code works when I replace the spaces in your string with tabs. https://dotnetfiddle.net/kQ6l5z

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that there are no tabs in your line string.

Trying this:

```
string line = "aaa\tbbb\tccc\tdd!\td!";
string[] lineArray = line.Split('\t');

Console.WriteLine($"{lineArray[0]}");
```

Works just fine. You have to define escape parameters in your strings as well.
Otherwise, you could look for more than one spaces (Which maybe your editor is set to produce when you enter a tab).